# How to install a pcf font so it's visible in xfontsel?

Tags: linux, fedora, fonts, xorg

I have a pcf font file which i need to be visible in xfontsel. I tried moving it to my `~/.fonts/` directory and running `fc-cache -f` but when I restart X and run `xfontsel`, the font isn't visible in the selections.

How do I properly install a font like this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just needed to run `xset +fp ~/.fonts/`